# How to use player own-made sprite as in-game sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-physics, phaser-framework, polygons

I am seeking for a way that allows players to draw their own characters and later to be able to play with them in-game. To make the concept very simple lets make the drawn player just a 2d shape or a group of lines and circles or even a mix of both. I think this can be decomposed in these steps:

---

1. An empty canvas is made for the user to create what he wants:

   By painting or something of that genre

   By using a specific polygon creation interface that allows dragging and molding shapes;

   **Note:** I was able to create a *way to paint on canvas* *** but I didn't find a way to let user drag and create shapes or something of that kind. I would more likely opt for the second option so some suggestions on how do this would be really appreciated.

```js
window.onload = init; 
 

function init() {


  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var painting = document.getElementById('paint');

  var paint_style = getComputedStyle(painting);
  canvas.width = "1024"
  canvas.height = "1024";

  var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  }, false);

  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#00CC99';

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);

  var onPaint = function() {
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Tojo - canvas draw</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">


</head>

<body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <div id="paint"></div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border: 3px solid black;"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

(paint on canvas snippet) ***

2. Somehow, I need to only get the user drawn / shaped creation from all the canvas. There should be a way to "surround" what the user has created and then save it:

   By (in the drawing case probably) checking only for the color comparison between the white and the player color;

   By, somehow, defining different points that all together would countain the user creation (either drawn or shaped);

   **Note:** In this case I am kind of lost. I have almost no clue of how this could be made. However, I have heard of box2d but I think it was more focused in C or something of that kind? Would it work and how could I do it?

3. I would finally have the user creation stored and ready to load it in game as an image of a sprite.

   I hope I could explain it all correctly. Can someone give me some orientation on this? FYI I am using Phaser.js as js game engine. (sorry for any mistakes, I am not very experienced with this matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you headed in the right direction:

1. Instead of drawing to the canvas, create a Phaser `bitmapData` object and have the user draw to that object.  See [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/bitmapdata/copy-bitmapdata) that shows how to draw to a `bitmapData` object.
2. If you follow #1, then all of the data that you want will be stored in the `bitmapData` object, and you can create a `Sprite` directly from your `bitmapData` object, e.g.:

---

```
// Create a bitmapData object for the user to draw on
var bmd = this.game.make.bitmapData(64, 64);

// code to draw on `bmd` goes here

// Create a Sprite based on the bitmapData from above
var userSprite = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, bmd);
```

Comment: Yep, that gives me something to go with already :) It is very practical and easy to implement too. I would still like to try the molding/dragging shapes interface but I will certainly check this possibility. I think I would need a way to, from all the bitmap get only what I painted and not all the "rectangle" bitmap.